# missing binary operator before token "("

Tags: c++, g++, preprocessor-directive

error:

```
cxx.cpp:5:13: error: missing binary operator before token "("
cxx.cpp:7:15: error: missing binary operator before token "("
```

code:

```
  #if definied(_WIN32) || definied(_WIN64) || definied(__WIN32__)
        const char * PORT = "COM1";
    #elif definied(__linux) || definied(__linux__) || definied(linux)
        const char * PORT = "dev/ttyS1";
    #else 
        const char * PORT = NULL;
    #endif
```

Questions:

1. the compiler is waiting an new `defined()` call?
2. it can detected any linux(and variants) or windows version?

thanks in advance.

Comment: As this can't possibly be your actual code ("definied" is clearly a copy-and-paste typo), this is tricky to answer.

Comment: You have misspelt `defined` all through that preprocessor code sample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misspelled `defined`:

```
#if definied(_WIN32) || definied(_WIN64) || definied(__WIN32__)

#elif definied(__linux) || definied(__linux__) || definied(linux)
```

should be:

```
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64) || defined(__WIN32__)

#elif defined(__linux) || defined(__linux__) || defined(linux)
```